# Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project's Expo config error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, deep-linking

I have 0 idea why this is happening because I have not changed anything in my apps `app.config.js` or `app.json` since checking out my current branch.

I added deep linking to my app a while ago, and everything has been fine. I have been trying to commit my changes, but Jest keeps throwing the error:

`` Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project's Expo config (app.config.js or app.json) for bare or production apps. Manually providing a `scheme` property can circumvent this error. Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/guides/linking/ ``

Which makes no sense to me, as there is a `scheme` property in the `app.json` and I have had no problems with this before.

I found a similar issue on GitGub [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11754)

Their solution involved manually adding the scheme to the `createMockConstants.js` file, but after taking a look, I already had this.

I appreciate I have not added any code/files but I don't see what good they would be as I mentioned, I already have the `scheme` property, and none of these files have changed.

Thanks